# Insert not rollbacked in @Transactional method on ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

```
@Service
public class TransferService {

    @Autowired
    TransferRepository transferRepository;
    @Autowired
    AccountRepository accountRepository;


    @Transactional(REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void transfer(Account fromAccount, Account toAccount, 
        BigDecimal amount) throws InterruptedException {


    fromAccount.setBalance(fromAccount.getBalance().subtract(amount));
    accountRepository.save(fromAccount);

    if(fromAccount.getId() == 1L){
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(10000);
    }

    toAccount.setBalance(toAccount.getBalance().add(amount));
    accountRepository.save(toAccount);

    transferRepository.save(new Transfer(fromAccount, toAccount,amount));
    }
}
```

Initial state in db table `Account`:

```
id | balance | version    
1  | 100     | 0    
2  | 100     | 0
```

`Transfer` table is empty.

When I call:

```
 1. transfer(account1, account2, 10);  
 2. transfer(account2, account1, 20);
```

db table `Account`:

```
id | balance | version    
1  | 120     | 0    
2  | 80      | 0
```

db table `Transfer`:

```
id | ammount | fromAccountId | toAccountId    
1  | 20      | 2             | 1        
2  | 10      | 1             | 2
```

The log clearly says that it is going to rollback: `Transfer#2`, `Account#2` and `Account#1`, BUT IT DOES NOT IT ROLLBACKS ONLY ACCOUNTS BUT TRANSFER WITH ID 2 IS THERE BUT SHOULD BE ROLL-BACKED.

ANY HELP SUPER APPRECIATED !!!

LOG:

> 2018-01-14 12:14:27.652 DEBUG 16006 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManagerCommitting JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[EntityKey[com.erabanq.entity.Transfer#2], EntityKey[com.erabanq.entity.Account#2], EntityKey[com.erabanq.entity.Account#1]],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])]
>
> 2018-01-14 12:14:27.657 ERROR 16006 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl        : HHH000346: Error during managed flush [Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1]
>
> 2018-01-14 12:14:27.658  INFO 16006 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
>
> 2018-01-14 12:14:27.678 DEBUG 16006 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Initiating transaction rollback after commit exception
>   org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

HERE IS DB LOG:

```
>START...............................
>2018-01-14T15:48:03.913784Z         8 Query     set session transaction read only    
>2018-01-14T15:48:03.913963Z         8 Query     SET autocommit=0    
>2018-01-14T15:48:03.921491Z         8 Query     select account0_.id as id1_0_0_, account0_.balance as balance2_0_0_, account0_.version as version3_0_0_ from account account0_ where account0_.id=1    
>2018-01-14T15:48:03.930767Z         8 Query     commit    
>2018-01-14T15:48:03.930929Z         8 Query     SET autocommit=1    
>2018-01-14T15:48:03.931281Z         8 Query     select @@session.tx_read_only    
>2018-01-14T15:48:03.931607Z         8 Query     set session transaction read write    
>2018-01-14T15:48:03.932052Z         8 Query     set session transaction read only    
>2018-01-14T15:48:03.932173Z         8 Query     SET autocommit=0    
>2018-01-14T15:48:03.932750Z         8 Query     select account0_.id as id1_0_0_, account0_.balance as balance2_0_0_, account0_.version as version3_0_0_ from account account0_ where account0_.id=2    
>2018-01-14T15:48:03.933613Z         8 Query     commit    
>2018-01-14T15:48:03.933744Z         8 Query     SET autocommit=1    
>2018-01-14T15:48:03.933968Z         8 Query     select @@session.tx_read_only    
>2018-01-14T15:48:03.934134Z         8 Query     set session transaction read write    
>2018-01-14T15:48:03.937186Z         8 Query     SET autocommit=0    
>2018-01-14T15:48:11.995802Z         9 Query     set session transaction read only    
>2018-01-14T15:48:11.996386Z         9 Query     SET autocommit=0    
>2018-01-14T15:48:11.999184Z         9 Query     select account0_.id as id1_0_0_, account0_.balance as balance2_0_0_, account0_.version as version3_0_0_ from account account0_ where account0_.id=2    
>2018-01-14T15:48:12.002778Z         9 Query     commit    
>2018-01-14T15:48:12.003217Z         9 Query     SET autocommit=1    
>2018-01-14T15:48:12.003848Z         9 Query     select @@session.tx_read_only    
>2018-01-14T15:48:12.004822Z         9 Query     set session transaction read write    
>2018-01-14T15:48:12.006758Z         9 Query     set session transaction read only     
>2018-01-14T15:48:12.008320Z         9 Query     SET autocommit=0    
>2018-01-14T15:48:12.012266Z         9 Query     select account0_.id as id1_0_0_, account0_.balance as balance2_0_0_, account0_.version as version3_0_0_ from account account0_ where account0_.id=1    
>2018-01-14T15:48:12.015808Z         9 Query     commit    
>2018-01-14T15:48:12.016214Z         9 Query     SET autocommit=1    
>2018-01-14T15:48:12.016792Z         9 Query     select @@session.tx_read_only    
>2018-01-14T15:48:12.017278Z         9 Query     set session transaction read write    
>2018-01-14T15:48:12.018332Z         9 Query     SET autocommit=0
>2018-01-14T15:48:12.078209Z         9 Query     insert into transfer (ammount, from_id, to_id, type) values (15, 2, 1, null)    
>2018-01-14T15:48:12.082738Z         9 Query     update account set balance=85.00, version=1 where id=2 and version=0    
>2018-01-14T15:48:12.084494Z         9 Query     update account set balance=115.00, version=1 where id=1 and version=0    
>2018-01-14T15:48:12.084946Z         9 Query     commit    
>2018-01-14T15:48:12.085086Z         9 Query     SET autocommit=1    
>2018-01-14T15:48:13.952199Z         8 Query     insert into transfer (ammount, from_id, to_id, type) values (10, 1, 2, null)    
>2018-01-14T15:48:13.954992Z         8 Query     update account set balance=90.00, version=1 where id=1 and version=0    
>2018-01-14T15:48:13.956614Z         8 Query     rollback    
>2018-01-14T15:48:13.957371Z         8 Query     SET autocommit=1
```

I am using Spring Data JPA 2.1, hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar

Comment: OMG, After 2 days of investigating it seems that very same code works on postgres :( Maybe the difference between REPEATABLE READ (default on mysql) and READ COMMITED (default on posgres) ???

Comment: The same code works with DB Derby, H2 and Postgress. So I belive it is a bug in: mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.20, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Comment: First of all please try to be accurate with your question. You mentioned two operations:
- account1 --(10)--> account2
- account2 --(20)--> account1
but the DB log you pasted shows something else:
- account2 --(15)--> account1
- account1 --(10)--> account2

So, either you have some concurrency issues or you aren't correctly describing the issue.

Comment: There's nothing unexpected in the end result.

Immediately before the last two DML statements (insert and update) you have set autocommit=1, so both operations will commit immediately, the roolback won't do anything there.

Also note that the last update filters by id=1 and version=0 but at this point the Account#1 already has version=1 (updated a few lines above). So it is a no-op. Actually this is why your are getting the exception that originated the alleged transaction rollback: "Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1"

Comment: You have to distinguish between thread 8 and thread 9. There are two separated threads/transactions in DB.

Comment: Right, I missed that. But then this is even more convoluted. The database log sequence of events doesn't end up in the situation you described. It leads to two account records, one with balance of 115 and the other with 85, and one transaction with amount=15, from_id=2 and to_id=1. Not at all what you described above.

Comment: This is happening because those are [MyISAM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/myisam-storage-engine.html) tables, which don't support transactions. You should change your application in order to create [InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-introduction.html) tables instead.